# How to integrate Aurora Postgresql with AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-aurora

I need to create a trigger in Aurora PostgresSQL which should push newly inserted row data on AWS SQS.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Invoke an AWS Lambda function from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html) by using the `aws_lambda` extension.

This could be triggered by a standard Postgres trigger on `INSERT`.

You would need to write an AWS Lambda function that then sends a message to Amazon SQS.

So, the total flow is:

```
SQL INSERT -> Postgres Trigger -> aws_lambda extension -> AWS Lambda function -> Send message to SQS queue
```